# How do we show the set, for example A={1,2,3} follows the axiom of regularity? (According to Zermelo-Frankel axiomatic set theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Axiom of regularity:**

Every non-empty set x contains a member y such that x and y are disjoint sets.
\begin{align*}
\forall x (x\ne \phi \Rightarrow \exists y \epsilon x (y \cap x = \phi))
\end{align*}

As I have taken the set as a subset of natural numbers, and they are not Sets themselves. i.e 1 is not a set. As all the elements of A are not sets, how can we show the above axiom is satisfied?

we can't show  $1 \cap A = \phi$, as 1 is a number and A is a set. incompatibility of the operation $\cap$. (if I am not wrong.)

Comment: In the context of ZF where that axiom is found, everything is a set, including integers. The usual set-up is $0$ is the empty set, $1$ = {$0$}, ...,  $n$ = {$0,1,...,n-1$}.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get your point. On what basis are you taking that setup?

Comment: See the axioms of [Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html) and see [Natural numbers: Constructions based on set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Constructions_based_on_set_theory)

Comment: You are wrong. But your first mistake is not searching for a previously asked question.

Comment: If we admit [atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement) (i.e. objects that are not sets) in our set theory, the corresponding form of the Axiom will be: $x \ne \emptyset \to \exists y \ (y \in x \to \forall z \ (z \in y \to z \notin x))$.